# How to find line index then rewrite it in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

Hello I have a simple problem I need to find specific lines in txt file they have to contain 'LG' which look like this:

```
>NC_037638.1 Apis mellifera strain DH4 linkage group LG1, Amel_HAv3.1, whole genome shotgun sequence
```

then I need to replace number in this case `NC_037638.1` with `LG1`
The LG and number will differ in each line

the result should look like this:

```
>LG1, Apis mellifera strain DH4 linkage group LG1, Amel_HAv3.1, whole genome shotgun sequence
```

I have like 3 mil of lines in a file and I need to find only those with LG followed by some number like in the example `LG1`

So basically i need to get from this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

I wrote something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ "LG" ]]; then
        echo $line | awk ' { t = $1; $1 = $8; print; } '  | sed -e 's/^/>/' >> nowy.txt
    else
        echo $line >> nowy.txt
    fi
done < kopia_pliku_docelowego
```

and it works but its ultra slow it takes like 3 minutes for the script to end

I thought out about solution and i figured i can grep for line index and change only those lines then swap old lines on the same index as new rewritten one.

I know how to find index `(grep -n)`
and i know how to change the line (talking about swaping number with LG)
but I don't know how to put it all together.

I would really appreciate some help

Comment: You are searching for all lines containing the string `LG` somewhere, not only those following a number. To match a line for having LG with a number, would be `[[ $line == *LG[0-9]* ]]`.

Comment: @anubhava : This would replace every string NC_037638.1 by LG1, not even in lines which don't contain any LG.

Comment: @antekkalafior: For each single line matching the pattern, you are creating 2 child processes (`awk` and `sed`). I would do everything either in bash or in awk only.

Comment: The values after LG changes the same goes to the number in front. every line has a different value. so i need to find only those lines which contains LG and swap its front line with LG. I have 3mil lines but only about 2k contains LG

Comment: @antekkalafior: So if a line has `LG101` then you want to replace `NC_037638.1` with `LG101`?

Comment: @anubhava thats correct

Comment: I know, this is what your awk program is caring for. I was just talking about **selecting** the line. Your program would also select a line starting with `>LG_037638.1 Apis mellifera ...`, even if there is no other LG in it.

Comment: @user1934428 maybe thats why it is so slow. as I said this script works but it just  takes too long for my needs

Comment: That's why I said that you should avoid the child processes.....

Comment: `while read | awk` will typically run many times slower than just `awk`.  Stop using the `while` loop; let `awk` read the input directly. It's good at that.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I understand but how should I do that? Im new to bash so i don't really understand its syntax

Comment: Please [edit] your question to replace those images with concise, testable sample input and expected output that we can copy/paste to test with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand the problem description.  It sounds like you just want to replace the first column with the 8th column in any line that contains `LG`.  If that's the case, just do:

```
awk '/LG/{ $1 = $8 }1' kopia_pliku_docelowego > nowy.txt
```

but perhaps you want to restrict the match so that you only do the replacements when 'LG' appears in the 8th column.  You could do that with:

```
awk '$8 ~ /LG/{ $1 = $8 }1'
```

If you require that `LG` be followed by a string of digits, use:

```
awk '$8 ~ /LG[0-9]+/{ $1 = $8 }1'
```

If you have lines in which the 8th column is `LGxxxAAA` (non string values following the digits) and you only want to replace the first column with that portion of the string that matches `LG[0-9+]`, you could use:

```
awk 'match($8,/LG[0-9]+/){ $1 = substr($8,0,RLENGTH) }1'
```

`awk` can undoubtedly solve your problem, but you need to clarify exactly what you're trying to match.  Your `sed` solution seems to be inserting a leading `>` which does not seem necessary according to your description.  More specificity is required.

Comment: This is exaclty what I've been looking for. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You may do this in a single `sed`:

```sh
sed -i.bak -E 's/^>NC_037638\.1(.* (LG[0-9]+))/>\2\1/' file

cat file

>LG1 Apis mellifera strain DH4 linkage group LG1, Amel_HAv3.1, whole genome shotgun sequence
```

**Explanation:**

- `^>`: Match `>` after start position
- `NC_037638\.1`: Match text `NC_037638.1`
- `(.*` : Nn capture group #1 match & capture any text followed by a space followed by...
- `(LG[0-9]+))`: Match `LG` followed by 1+ numbers in capture group #2
- `>\2\1`: Replacement part to have `>` followed by `LG` substring (what we captured in group #2) followed by back-reference of capture group #1

Comment: It's not what i'm looking for. I rewrote the question so it should be more understandable

Comment: Unfortunately putting images instead of the actual text makes it very difficult to understand. If you replace images with small text snippet it will be more clear

Comment: `It's not what i'm looking for` Please clarify this because this answer is based on the question I asked in comments and you replied `thats correct`

Answer (score 0):

Just awk, maybe:

```
awk '{
  for(i=1;i<NF-1;i++)
    if($i=="linkage" && $(i+1)=="group")
      break
  if(i!=NF-1)
    $1=$(i+2)
  print
}' file.txt
```

We search for the two consecutive words "*linkage*" and "*group*", just in case they are not always at the same position in the lines. I suspect it could happen because of "*Apis mellifera*" that looks like a single field containing a space. If we find these two words we replace the first field with the one that follows "*linkage group*".

If the field following "*linkage group*" must be further constrained, e.g. to be `LGnnn` where `nnn` is some string of digits, we can change a bit the condition:

```
awk '{
  for(i=1;i<NF-1;i++)
    if($i=="linkage" && $(i+1)=="group" && $(i+2) ~ /^LG[[:digit:]]+/)
      break;
  if(i!=NF-1)
    $1=$(i+2)
  print
}' file.txt
```